# Visual Studio 2015 Project exists but no longer shown in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have one solution that has been effectively cloned from another one. The cloned solution works fine but the original has mysteriously stopped working.

The solution file contains the project

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CMS", "CMS\CMS.csproj", "{0EABB8B8-2784-4BBA-B2E8-5D7B4A302182}"
EndProject
```

And the CMS.csproj project file appears in the CMS subfolder.

But the project doesn't appear in Solution Explorer when I load the solution. Effectively the solution is empty.

I can load the project file directly, and VS will then show it in solution explorer inside a solution with the same name as the project. But I don't understand why my original solution is not working. There are no error messages.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've worked out the solution, but the answer just poses another bunch of questions.

Comparing the .suo file of the two projects, I found that the one that doesn't work has had an extra level of indentation added (ie a tab character in front of each line). See below.

When I took these extra tabs out, the Project reappeared in the solution explorer.

This poses the following two questions (if you have any ideas, please add them in the comments)...

I haven't edited the .suo file. Ever. How did these tabs get added?

Given that the .suo file already contains tabs to indent sections. And given that the sections are clearly defined by [SectionName] End[SectionName] statements, why would Visual Studio not simply ignore the tabs?

```
    Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
    # Visual Studio 14
    VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.24720.0
    MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
    Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CMS", "CMS\CMS.csproj", "{0EABB8B8-2784-4BBA-B2E8-5D7B4A302182}"
    EndProject
    Global
        GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
            Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
            Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
            {0EABB8B8-2784-4BBA-B2E8-5D7B4A302182}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
            {0EABB8B8-2784-4BBA-B2E8-5D7B4A302182}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
            {0EABB8B8-2784-4BBA-B2E8-5D7B4A302182}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
            {0EABB8B8-2784-4BBA-B2E8-5D7B4A302182}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
            HideSolutionNode = FALSE
        EndGlobalSection
    EndGlobal
```